# Second activity spinner display based on first activity spinner selection

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have UI with two layout and two activity with two spinner and other buttons.

First layout is login activity where we will select the "Spinner1" data from database and press login "button" which will take to next layout.

**Requirement is**

Based on first layout(Firstactivity) Spinner1 selection second layout Spinner2 should change.

**Note : Spinner2 change based on Spinner1 is working fine in second layout.**

Tried with different way but could not.Need some expert view on the same.

as is

First Layout Activity

```js
public class Loginactivity extends Activity {
  Spinner s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;
  Cursor spinner1csr, spinner2csr, spinner3csr, spinner5csr;
  SimpleCursorAdapter sca, sca2, sca3, sca5;
  LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
  Button login;
  Button registerr;
  EditText enterpassword, et;
  TextView forgetpass;
  String st;
  video_view video_view;
  video_view videoView;
  String TAG = "VideoPlayer";
  private MediaController mediaController;
  DatabaseHandler dbhndlr;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
    dbhndlr = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    registerr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
    enterpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_edt);
    forgetpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    long spinner1_selected = 0;
    loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

    manageCustomerSpinner();
    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DCIM/steprock/steprock.mp4");


    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
        Log.i(TAG, "Duration = " +
          videoView.getDuration());
      }
    });
    videoView.start();

    registerr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Loginactivity.this, Registration.class);
        startActivity(i);
      }
    });

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Password = enterpassword.getText().toString();

        String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(Password);

        if (Password.equals(storedPassword)) {
          Toast.makeText(Loginactivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Intent ii = new Intent(Loginactivity.this, SpinnerEx4Activity.class);

          startActivity(ii);
        } else if (Password.equals("")) {
          Toast.makeText(Loginactivity.this, "Please Enter Your Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(Loginactivity.this, "Password Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  public void manageCustomerSpinner() {
    spinner5csr = dbhndlr.getCustomers();
    if (sca5 == null) {
      sca5 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        spinner5csr,
        new String[] {
          DatabaseHandler.COL_CUSTOMER_NAME,
            // DatabaseHandler.COL_CUSTOMER_ID
        },
        new int[] {
          android.R.id.text1,
            // android.R.id.text2
        },
        0
      );
      s5.setAdapter(sca5);
      s5.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          manageLotSpinner(id); //<<<<<<<<<< WHENEVER CUSTOMER IS SELECTED THE LOT SPINNER IS MANAGED >>>>>>>>>>
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent) {

        }
      });
    } else {
      sca5.swapCursor(spinner5csr);
    }


    forgetpass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Loginactivity.this);
        dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.forget_search);
        dialog.show();

        final EditText security = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.securityhint_edt);
        final TextView getpass = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        //Button ok=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.getpassword_btn);
        Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);


        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
          }
        });

        dialog.show();
      }
    });
  }


  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Close The Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
  }



}
```

Second layout spinner details.

```js
 public void manageLotSpinner(long id) {
        spinner2csr = dbhndlr.getLotsPerCustomer1(id);
        if (sca2 == null) {
            sca2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    spinner2csr,
                    new String[]{
                            DatabaseHandler.ROUTE,
                            //DatabaseHelper.COL_LOT_ID
                    },
                    new int[]{
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            //android.R.id.text2
                    },
                    0
            );
            s1.setAdapter(sca2);
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    manageSpinner3(spinner2csr.getString(spinner2csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.ROUTE)));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

        } else {
            sca2.swapCursor(spinner2csr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can pass the selected spinner value from 1st activity to second and there you can do your logic to show the 2nd spinner in 2nd activity.

Comment: its not working ??

Comment: can you share me the code so that i can run and check?